# PL SQL run DML transaction without triggering trigger

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I want to insert data to table that has associated triggers. Is it possible to tell database not to trigger specific trigger when inserting data.

Comment: Not for a single transaction, no. But you can disable the trigger for all users temporarily if you know you will be the only one touching the table. This is definitely something to be avoided, however, so consider carefully if you really need to do this.

Comment: I seem to recall that you can set a global variable in a package, and have the trigger read that to see if it should fire or not.

Comment: I've used package global variables and application contexts for this purpose before.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know why this is needed.
In any way, i suggest adding some business logic inside the trigger itself in a way not to process data it should not.
Say for example  insert into table_name value1, value2,

In the trigger itself say

if :NEW.COL1 = "PLEASE_NO_TRIGGER" then

```
 return    --dont to anything
```

end if;

As stated , this solution is far from being standard, but it can serve u if needed.